# '.class' expected unexpected type. required: value, found:class

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Vector_par_impar {

    protected int v1[]=new int[20];
    protected int v2[]=new int[20];

    public static String Par_impar (int i1,int i2,int num, int v1[], int v2[]) {
        if ((num%2)==0){ //par
            v1[i1]=num;
            return ""+v1[i1];
        }
        else {//impar
            v2[i2]=num;
            return""+v2[i2];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n=0,vv1=0,vv2=0;
       int aux1[]=new int[20];
       int aux2[]=new int[20];

       for(int il=0;il<20;il++){
           System.out.println("Ingrese el dato "+il);
           n=teclado.nextInt();
           if ((n%2)==0){ //par
               aux1[il]=n;
               vv1=vv1+1;
           }
           else {//impar
               aux2[il]=n;
               vv2=vv2+1;
           }
        }
        System.out.println (Par_impar(vv1,vv2,n,aux1[],aux2[])); //ErrorHERE!help :(

//'.class' expected_unexpected_type. required: value, found:class (this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
aux1[],aux2[]
```

in

```
System.out.println (Par_impar(vv1,vv2,n,aux1[],aux2[]));
```

is not valid java notation. Use

```
System.out.println (Par_impar(vv1,vv2,n,aux1,aux2));
```

To pass the variables as arguments to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the array variables names, not `aux1[], aux2[]`

```
System.out.println (Par_impar(vv1,vv2,n,aux1, aux2));
```